# Accidentally recovered the wrong file with vim

Tags: vim, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04

I coded some stuff in Pluma and later forgot that i worked on it and turn my raspberry pi 3 off (Ubuntu mate 16...) After that i saw that i lost some code and it really didnt matter so hard. I wanted to work on it again and did it per Putty terminal and vim... after i opened the file, vim said that i can recover some data because there was a .swp version and i pressed it... but... its an older file and i dont know how to go back or reverse that process because i didnt made much backups.

Comment: try to undo it
see this tread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385956/undo-recovery-from-swap-file-in-vim

Comment: It was too late for me to recognize that its an old file so i think its not possible but i spend the last 2 hours making a kinda better one.

Comment: But thanks anyway, next time i'll be more patient and be more carefully